# Polynomials in the extension of a complete field

Tags: general-topology, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory

I need some help in answering this exercise from Serre's Local Fields textbook:

Let K be a complete field, and let f(X) in K[X] be a separable irreducible polynomial of degree n. Let L/K be the extension of degree n defined by f. Show that for every polynomial h(X) of degree n that is close enough to f, h(X) is irreducible and the extension (L_h)/K defined by h is isomorphic to L.

Comment: You can take the splitting field $L$ of $f$, notice that the roots of $f$ in $L$ are approximate roots of $h$, so that Hensel's lemma gives you roots of $h$ in $L$ close to the roots of $L$, and then apply Krasner's lemma.

Comment: sorry, replace $L$ in my comment with say $F$ (I missed that you used $L$ in your question)

Comment: This proof works if $K$ is a complete local field. The OP supposes only that $K$ is a complete field. But the exercise being in Serre's "Corps Locaux", I guess that the OP forgot to precise that $K$ is supposed to be local.